# Finding discrepancy on work end date and stay duration

Tags: papers-please

It is day 27, December 19, and the new Access Permit has been introduced to merge the identity supplement and entry permit.

Later in the day, a woman enters my booth claiming entry for work purposes, for a time of 3 months.

Checking the work end date on her Work Pass, I notice that the work pass implies that she's working for 4 months.  I try to highlight the discrepancy between the access permit time and and work end date, but it solely gives me a "No Correlation" error.  On this note, I quit the game and dash over here to pose my question.

**How do you highlight the discrepancy between the work end date and stay duration?**

**Note:** Highlighting the two individual values worked on the entry permit, but not the access permit.

Comment: "It is day 27, January (something)," Are you sure? The game ends on December 25th.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  Day 27 is December 19th.

Comment: What error did you get? "Matching Data" or "No Correlation"?

Comment: No correlation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When in discrepancy mode, click on the speaker (that's the thing that looks like a waffle two to the left of the clock) and the date in the document. The speaker keeps track of everything the npc says, and it has a document which can be pulled out and reviewed.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the work end date can be a little unclear, but it's actually the date the pass authorizes them to work until, not an exact date that they will leave. There is only a discrepancy there if the date is too early. The way you highlighted would work if there was a discrepancy.